# Oracle optimizer equijoin of 3 tables

Tags: oracle

i have 3 tables in a oracle 11g database. I don't have access to trace file or explain plan anymore. I join the 3 table on the date field like:

```
select * from a,b,c where a.date = b.date and b.date = c.date
```

and that takes forever.

when I

```
select * from a,b,c where a.date = b.date and b.date = c.date and a.date = c.date
```

its fast. but should that make a difference?

Comment: Without more information like query plans, this is unanswerable.  Should it make a difference?  No.  Does it make a difference?  It can.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but it looks like a transitive dependency. that's to say if `a.date = b.date and b.date = c.date` then `a.date = c.date`. You can modify your query rather like

```
select a.* 
from a
join b on a.date = b.date
join c on a.date = c.date;
```

I would also have a index on `date` column for all this 3 tables since that's the column you are joining on.

Comment: there is index on all the join columns

Comment: An index is unlikely to be of interest to the optimiser, if you have to access all of the rows. I think that using the ANSI style join is definitely to be encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the database does not rewrite queries if the joins are such that A = B, B = C ==> A = C so it's stuck to using what its given.

Consider the following:

```
create table a (dt date);
create table b (dt date);
create table c (dt date);
```

Now fill in the tables so that a is the smallest (5 rows), b is the biggest (100 rows), and c is in the middle (50 rows). Also, so that not all rows in b and c will join to a just to make things a bit more interesting.

```
insert into a
select to_date('2015-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') + rownum - 1
from dual
connect by level <= 5
;

insert into b
select to_date('2015-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') + mod(rownum, 10)
from dual
connect by level <= 100
;

insert into c
select to_date('2015-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') + mod(rownum, 10)
from dual
connect by level <= 50
;
```

I'm going to bypass statistics for now and leave it totally up to the database on how to figure out a plan.

Take 1: without the join from a to c:

```
explain plan for
select *
  from a
     , b 
     , c
where a.dt = b.dt
  and b.dt = c.dt
;
```

and here's the plan:

```
select *
from table(dbms_xplan.display())
;
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |   250 |  6750 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN          |      |   250 |  6750 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN         |      |    50 |   900 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| A    |     5 |    45 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| B    |   100 |   900 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | C    |    50 |   450 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("B"."DT"="C"."DT")
   2 - access("A"."DT"="B"."DT")

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

First off, since there were no statistics on the tables, Oracle chose to sample the data first so it wasn't going in blind. In this case, table a joins to b first, then the result of that joins to c.

Take 2: introduce the a.dt = c.dt condition:

```
explain plan for
select *
  from a
     ,  b 
     ,  c
where a.dt = b.dt
  and b.dt = c.dt
  and a.dt = c.dt
;

select *
from table(dbms_xplan.display())
;
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |    25 |   675 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN          |      |    25 |   675 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN         |      |    25 |   450 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| A    |     5 |    45 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| C    |    50 |   450 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | B    |   100 |   900 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("A"."DT"="B"."DT" AND "B"."DT"="C"."DT")
   2 - access("A"."DT"="C"."DT")

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

And there you go. The order of the joins has switched now that Oracle has been given the extra join path. (FYI, this is the same plan if using just a.dt = b.dt and a.dt = c.dt.)

BUT, notice anything? The estimates are not right anymore. It's guessing 25 rows in the end, not 250. So, the extra condition is actually causing some confusion.

Without the b.dt = c.dt, though, same join path, different estimates (same end result as the first one):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |   250 |  6750 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN          |      |   250 |  6750 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN         |      |    25 |   450 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| A    |     5 |    45 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| C    |    50 |   450 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | B    |   100 |   900 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("A"."DT"="B"."DT")
   2 - access("A"."DT"="C"."DT")

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

Long story a little longer, since the database isn't going to assume any join paths for you, adding one in your query gives the database more options and as such can change its plan...and a change in plan can certainly affect how fast the results are returned.

Answer (score 0):

**This is Your Query.....**

```
select * from a,b,c where a.date = b.date and .date = c.date and a.date = c.date
```

**Now As per my view ..**

```
SELECT * FROM a
JOIN B USING(date)
JOIN C USING(date);
```